# How can I set cache-control using Write-S3Object with S3 and Cloudfront Distributions?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have been doing it like this but now it no longer seems to work (August 2015):

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName "example-bucket" 
   -KeyPrefix "app/admin/partials" 
   -Folder 'app/admin/partials' -SearchPattern '*.html' 
   -HeaderCollection @{"Cache-Control" = "public,max-age=120"}
```

Did something change recently?  When I check in S3 there is no header information set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **-Metadata** parameter in your query, changing your `-HeaderCollection @{"Cache-Control" = "public,max-age=120"}` parameter to `-Metadata @{"Cache-Control" = "public,max-age=120"}` works fine, and can be seen in AWS web console.

Here is working snippet

```
 Write-S3Object -BucketName myBucket -file "test.json" -Metadata
 @{"Cache-Control" = "public,max-age=120"}
```

This was run using the following version of Powershell.

```
PS C:\Users\DanielH1> Get-AWSPowerShellVersion

AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell
Version 3.1.5.1
Copyright 2012-2015 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

Amazon Web Services SDK for .NET
Version 3.1.0.2
Copyright 2009-2015 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

Release notes: https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/PowerShell

This software includes third party software subject to the following copyrights:
- Logging from log4net, Apache License
[http://logging.apache.org/log4net/license.html]
```

Here is a link to documentation for reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Write-S3Object.html

Answer (score 0):

What happened to me was that **HeaderCollection** worked perfectly fine when uploading a single **File** but not when uploading a **Folder**.

It turns out that **Metadata** do works with **Folders** although you end up with 2 headers, in my case:

```
Cache-Control max-age=9999
x-amz-meta-cache-control max-age=9999
```

and to make things even strager using only **Metadata** with a single **File** didn't work

So I decided to add both parameters (HeaderCollection and Metadata) in my @params variable and let the script put both headers on all my files.

Hope it helps somebody :)